# Need help instantiating a controller and storyboard scene from controller SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I have a controller that is using a Singleton to change SKScenes in a single storyboard scene.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate, FBLoginViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MapViewControllerDelegate {
    var sharedInstance = Singleton.sharedInstance

    var skView:SKView!
    var scene:GameScene! = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene

    var searchedTypes = ["bakery", "bar", "cafe", "grocery_or_supermarket", "restaurant"]
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var adHelper: AdHelper = AdHelper()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        // Configure the view.
        skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(kSceneTransitionSpeed))
}

// LOAD MAP SCENE

    func showMap(){
      let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MapController") as UIViewController

      self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

In my game scene I have a button that I am calling to this controller to change to the other scene in the storyboard because I don't have a layout button to use an IBAction

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var sharedInstance = Singleton.sharedInstance

    let playButton = Button(imageNamed:"playButton");
    let highscoresButton = Button(imageNamed:"highscoresButton");
    let creditsButton = Button(imageNamed:"creditsButton");
    let moreGamesButton = Button(imageNamed: "moreGamesButton")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        // background
        let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
        background.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
        self.addChild(background)


        // main image
        let main = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "main")
        main.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
        self.addChild(main)

        // buttons
        moreGamesButton.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2 + playButton.size.width, main.position.y + main.size.height/2 + playButton.size.height)
        self.sharedInstance.addChildFadeIn(moreGamesButton, target: self)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self);

            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.moreGamesButton {

                var gameController: GameViewController=GameViewController()
                gameController.showMap()

            }

        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

When I click this I don't get a defined error just hits a break and it the thread I get "Swift dynamic cast failed".

Can I not call the controller like that within my scene or is is it a problem in instantiating the other controller?